Tengo un problema con actualizar un estado y dentro de ese estado un array en React
tengo que hacer una especia de hoja de formalizacion deonde en el handleChange capturo y añado todos lo valores a formData, y en Recalcular valores me tiene que hacer los calculos pertinentes para calcular comisiones dependiendo del porcentaje que tengan.
añado codigo


const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        propiedades: [],
        aaff: [],
        colaboradores: [],
    });

const handleChange = (e, propiedad) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        let tipoCom = formData?.tipoCom /*parseFloat(formData.tipoCom) / 100 ||  0*/;
        let porLae = parseFloat(formData.porLae) / 100 || 0;
        let porAaff = Array.isArray(formData.aaff) ? formData.aaff[0]?.porAaff || 0 : formData?.aaff?.porAaff || 0;
        let porCola = Array.isArray(formData.colaboradores) ? formData.colaboradores[0]?.porCola || 0 : formData?.colaboradores?.porCola || 0;
        let porCap = parseFloat(formData.porCaptador) / 100 || 0;
        let porVend = parseFloat(formData.porVendedor) / 100 || 0;
        let porCoor = parseFloat(formData.porCoor) / 100 || 0;
        let porRespo = parseFloat(formData.porRespo) / 100 || 0;
        

        setFormData(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            ["total"]: importe,
            ["fechaOperacion"]: fechaOperacion
        }));

        if (name === 'accion') {
            setFormData(prevState => ({ ...prevState, [name]: value }));
        };
        if (name === 'haya') {
            setHaya(!haya);
            setFormData(prevState => ({ ...prevState, [name]: e.target?.checked }));
        };
        if (name === 'opCompartida') {
            const isCompartida = e.target?.checked;
            setIsCompartida(isCompartida);
            setFormData(prevState => ({
                ...prevState,
                [name]: isCompartida,
                porLae: !isCompartida ? 0 : prevState.porLae
            }));
            let updatedPorLae = 0;
            if (isCompartida === true) {
                updatedPorLae = formData.porLae / 100;
            }
            recalcularValores(isCompartida, tipoCom, updatedPorLae, porAaff, porCola, porCap, porVend, porCoor, porRespo);

        };
        if(name === 'comision'){
            const parsedValue = parseFloat(value);
            if (!importe || importe === 0 || isNaN(parsedValue)) {
                setComision(0);
                return;
            }
            setComision(parsedValue);
            let el_porcentaje = (parsedValue / importe) * 100;
            el_porcentaje = parseFloat(el_porcentaje.toFixed(2)); 
            
            setFormData(prevState => ({
                ...prevState,
                tipoCom: el_porcentaje,
                totalComisionNeta: parsedValue,  
            }));
            setTotalComision(parsedValue);
            recalcularValores(isCompartida, el_porcentaje, porLae, porCoor, porRespo, porAaff, porCap, porVend, porCola);
        }
        if (['direccion_propiedad', 'ciudad_propiedad', 'cp_propiedad', 'importe_propiedad', 'promocion'].includes(name)) {
            setPropedades(prevState =>
                prevState.map(prop =>
                    prop.id === propiedad.id ? { ...prop, [name.split('_')[0]]: value } : prop
                )
            );
            setFormData(prevState => ({
                ...prevState,
                propiedades: Array.isArray(prevState.propiedades) ?
                    prevState.propiedades.map(prop =>
                        prop.id === propiedad.id ? { ...prop, [name.split('_')[0]]: value } : prop
                    ) : []
            }));
        };
        if (['tipoCom', 'porLae','porCoor', 'porRespo', 'porAaff', 'porCola', 'porCaptador', 'porVendedor'].includes(name)) {
            const parsedValue = parseFloat(value) / 100;
          
            if (name === 'porCoor') {
                porCoor = parsedValue; 
            }
            if (name === 'porRespo') {
                porRespo = parsedValue;
            }
            if (name === 'porCaptador') {
                porCap = parsedValue;
            }
            if (name === 'porAaff') {
                setFormData(prevState => {
                    const newFormData = { ...prevState };
                    if (name === 'porAaff') {
                        if (!Array.isArray(newFormData.aaff)) {
                            newFormData.aaff = []; 
                        }
                        if (newFormData.aaff.length === 0) {
                            newFormData.aaff.push({ porAaff: value }); 
                        } else {
                            newFormData.aaff[0].porAaff = value; 
                        }
                    } else {
                        newFormData[name] = value;
                    }
                    return newFormData; 
                });
                porAaff = value;
                recalcularValores(isCompartida, tipoCom, porLae, porCoor, porRespo, porAaff, porCap, porVend, porCola);
            } 
            if (name === 'porCola') {
                setFormData(prevState => {
                    const newFormData = { ...prevState };
                    if (Array.isArray(newFormData.colaboradores)) {
                        if (newFormData.colaboradores.length > 0) {
                            newFormData.colaboradores[0].porCola = value;
                        } else {
                            newFormData.colaboradores.push({ porCola: value });
                        }
                    } else if (typeof newFormData.colaboradores === 'object' && newFormData.colaboradores !== null) {
                        newFormData.colaboradores.porCola = value;
                    } else {
                        newFormData.colaboradores = { porCola: value };
                    }

                    return newFormData;
                });
                porCola = value;
                recalcularValores(isCompartida, tipoCom, porLae, porCoor, porRespo, porAaff, porCaptador, porVend, porCola);
            }
            if (name === 'porVendedor') {
                porVend = parsedValue;
            }
            if (name === 'tipoCom') {
                tipoCom = value; 
                const nuevaComision = importe * (tipoCom / 100); 
                setComision(parseInt(nuevaComision));
                setTotalComision(parsedValue);

            }
            if (name === 'porLae') {
                porLae = parsedValue;
            }
            setFormData(prevState => ({ ...prevState, [name]: value }));
            recalcularValores(isCompartida, tipoCom, porLae, porCoor, porRespo, porAaff, porCap, porVend, porCola);
        }
        
        const UpdateedProps = propiedades?.map(prop => {
            return {
                id_prop: prop?.id,
                cp: prop?.cp,
                direccion: prop?.direccion,
                promocion: prop?.promocion,
                municipio: prop?.ciudad,
                importe: prop?.precioinmo || prop?.importe,
            }
        });
        setFormData(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            ["id_captador"]: formData.captador?.id,
            ["id_comprador"]: formData.comprador?.id,
            ["id_agVendedor"]: formData?.agenteVendedor?.id,
            ["id_vendedor"]: formData.vendedor?.id,
            ["propiedades"]: UpdateedProps

        }));
    };
    const recalcularValores = (
        isCompartida = false,
        tipoCom = 0,
        porLae = 0,
        porCoor = 0,
        porRespo = 0,
        porAaff = 0,
        porCap = 0,
        porVend = 0,
        porCola = 0,
    ) => {

        const importeNeto = comision * (1 - porLae);
        const totalComision = comision;
        const totalComisonNeta = isCompartida && porLae > 0 ? comision - importeNeto : comision;
        const importeCoordinador = parseFloat((totalComisonNeta * porCoor).toFixed(2));
        const importeResponsable = parseFloat((totalComisonNeta * porRespo).toFixed(2));
        const importeCaptador = parseFloat((totalComisonNeta * porCap).toFixed(2));
        const importeVendedor = parseFloat((totalComisonNeta * porVend).toFixed(2));
        const importeAaff = parseFloat((totalComisonNeta * porAaff).toFixed(2)) / 100 ;
        let sumRestos = 0;
        
        const importeColaborador = parseFloat((
            vinculo === 'AAFF' ? importeAaff
            :
                vinculo === 'VENDEDOR' ? importeVendedor
                :
                    vinculo === 'CAPTADOR' ? importeCaptador
                    :
                        totalComisonNeta) * parseFloat(porCola) / 100).toFixed(2);
        
        sumRestos = importeAaff + importeCaptador + importeVendedor;
        console.log(formData?.aaff);
        console.log(formData)
        // const miCol = colaborador?.map(col => ({
        //     id_col: col?.id,
        //     porCola: porCola,
        //     totalColaborador: vinculo === 'COLABORADOR' ? importeColaborador - importePrescriptor : importeColaborador,
        //     nombre: col?.nombre,
        //     apellidos: col?.apellidos
        // }));

        setFormData(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            // ["aaff"]: miAaff,
            // ["colaboradores"]: miCol,
            ["total"]: importe,
            ["totalCoor"]: importeCoordinador,
            ["totalRespo"]: importeResponsable,
            // //     ["totalCol"]: vinculo === 'COLABORADOR' ? importeColaborador - importePrescriptor : importeColaborador,
            ["totalCaptador"]: vinculo === 'CAPTADOR' ? importeCaptador - importeColaborador : importeCaptador,
            ["totalVendedor"]: vinculo === 'VENDEDOR' ? importeVendedor - importeColaborador : importeVendedor,
            // ["comisionTotal"]: totalComision,
            // ["comisionLae"]: totalComisonNeta,
            ["totalComisionNeta"]: isCompartida ? totalComisonNeta - sumRestos : totalComision - sumRestos,
        }));

        // setComision(comision);
        // setTotalComision(!isCompartida    ? totalComision - sumRestos : totalComisonNeta - sumRestos);
    };



la cosa es que cuando añado el porcentaje de un aaff hasta que no se vuelva a ejecutar handleChange no me aparecerá
  console.log(formData?.aaff); pero cuando hago   console.log(formData); si aparece
alguna idea sobre que está pasando, necesaramiamente es una array así que no puedo usar objetos.

Puedes agregar más código para poder reproducir el problema? Los snippets de código de este sitio admiten jQuery, React y otras librerías. Así podríamos darle a ejecutar y ver el problema
